# How to add ipcRenderer from Electron to Angular? Attached variables from preload script are undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, ipc

I am not sure how to use `ipcRenderer` in 'frontend' code of electron app.
In the documentation I have found examples that are using `require` but I don't have `require` available on the frontend. (I am using angular to create 'frontend' side)

In the electron docs - https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts
I have found an example how to attach variables from the main process to the window in renderer process but when I try to use attached variables I get `undefined`.

**main.js**

```
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    preload: './preload.js'
  });

  win.loadFile('dist/foobar/index.html') // I get index.html after building angular code

  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
   
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", {ipcRenderer}); //exposing ipcRenderer to the window in renderer process
```

**electron service (angular code)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ElectronService {

  constructor() { }

  getIpcRenderer(){
    return (<any>window).ipcRenderer;
  }
}
```

**angular component**

```
export class FoobarComponent {

  constructor(private es: ElectronService) {}

  test(){
    console.log(this.es.getIpcRenderer()); // this logs as undefined
  }
}
```

**My problem** 
In the code above you can see that `test()` prints undefined. Why is window.ipcRenderer undefined? I have also ran `console.log(window)` and I can't find `ipcRenderer` on the list of properties

Is there better way to expose ipcRenderer to my angular code? In the [doc linked above](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts) they are saying

> This feature is incredibly useful for two main purposes:
>
> 1. By exposing ipcRenderer helpers to the renderer, you can use inter-process communication (IPC)
>    to trigger main process tasks from the renderer (and vice-versa).
> 2. [...]

I assume that `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` is the best way since it is in the documentation but please let me know if this is outdated or if there is simply a better way.

---

**How I run my electron app**

1. I build angular code (`ng build --prod`)
2. I start electron app by running `electron .` (**main.js** is the entry point)

Comment: Just a two cents for anyone reading this post - you should NEVER expose whole ipcRenderer to your renderer process.
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload#communicating-between-processes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone makes the same mistake:

preload should be in `webPreferences` instead of directly in `BrowserWindow`

**wrong**

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    preload: './preload.js'
});
```

**correct**

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences:{
      preload: './preload.js'
    }
});
```